# Creating a new column by extracting values from dict in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data structure like this

| name | targets | imp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | {'codes':[3,4,6,199], 'region':'us', 'meta':''} | 200 |
| Diana | {'codes':[3,33,199], 'region':'us', 'meta':''} | 100 |

I am trying to make the final results one more column of extracted `codes` in `targets`,  like this

| name | targets | imp | targets.code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | {'codes':[3,4,6,199], 'region':'us', 'meta':''} | 200 | [3,4,6,199] |
| Diana | {'codes':[3,33,199], 'region':'us', 'meta':''} | 100 | [3,33,199] |

I tried doing

```
df['targets.code'] = df['targets'].apply(lambda x: x['codes'])
```

But it shows specifying on that line

```
[2022-01-14 19:53:33,660] {{taskinstance.py:1150}} ERROR - 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I really tried digging into a lot of posts but didn't find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `df['targets.code'] = [x['codes'] for x in df['targets'] ]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have bad data (empty fields) in your source under "targets" column, because the following works:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'Bob', 'targets': {'codes':[3,4,6,199], 'region':'us', 'meta':''}}])
print(df)
#  name                                            targets
# 0  Bob  {'codes': [3, 4, 6, 199], 'region': 'us', 'met...

df['targets.code'] = df['targets'].apply(lambda x: x['codes'])
print(df)
#   name                                            targets    targets.code
# 0  Bob  {'codes': [3, 4, 6, 199], 'region': 'us', 'met...  [3, 4, 6, 199]
```

Comment: In that case, what could I do to make it put an empty array by default?

Comment: Same as you would with normal code, e.g. the super-defensive: `lambda x: (x or {}).get('codes', [])`. Alternatively, I think can be cleaner to first normalize your data, filling `None` values with default values, etc.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.json_normalize`:

```
df['targets.code'] = pd.json_normalize(df['targets'])['codes']
print(df)

# Output
    name                                            targets  imp    targets.code
0    Bob  {'codes': [3, 4, 6, 199], 'region': 'us', 'met...  200  [3, 4, 6, 199]
1  Diana  {'codes': [3, 33, 199], 'region': 'us', 'meta'...  100    [3, 33, 199]
```

You can also use a comprehension:

```
df['targets.code'] = [x['codes'] if x else [] for x in df['targets']]
print(df)

# Output
    name                                            targets  imp    targets.code
0    Bob  {'codes': [3, 4, 6, 199], 'region': 'us', 'met...  200  [3, 4, 6, 199]
1  Diana  {'codes': [3, 33, 199], 'region': 'us', 'meta'...  100    [3, 33, 199]
2   Test                                               None   50              []
```

Comment: Seems like even `pd.json_normalize(df['targeting'])` gives the `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'` error. Could be because some of the rows doesn't have targets...?

Comment: Yes probably. You have to filter out rows before apply `pd.json_normalize`.

Comment: Is there a way to just put an empty array if `code` is not found?

Comment: I updated my answer can you check the second code?

Comment: I tried `json_normalize` with an empty entry but it doesn't raise an exception. Can you update your post with a such example?

Comment: The second solution worked! Thanks!